# Capture USB traffic from an Afterglow ps3 controller

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, wireshark, remote-control

I'm about to start a raspberry pi rc car project, and I wanted to use a wired usb Afterglow ps3 controller. I figured I would need to first interpret the data sent over USB from the controller when a button is pressed or the joystick is moved. Maybe I don't totally understand what I'm doing, if so please let me know if there's a better option. Anyway, how would I go about capturing the data sent from the controller? Is there a better way to do this other than wireshark (I wasn't able to figure out how to capture usb data using wireshark) or do I not even need to do this in order to accomplish what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are not bent on implementing it yourself, you can use any of the existing ps3 controller drivers for Linux.  See [sixlinux](http://www.pabr.org/sixlinux/sixlinux.en.html), [openaxis](http://code.google.com/p/openaxis/), or any HID api if you are willing to use it over Bluetooth.

There is even [an example](http://dhoium3009.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi-connecting-multiple-ps3-controllers-via-bluetooth/) of doing it with a Raspberry Pi.